# Difference between fuel pressure and fuel rail pressure

Tags: obd-ii, fuel-injection, pressure, fuel-line

In OBD PID wiki page, there are 2 PIDs listed: Fuel pressure and Fuel rail pressure. Are both of them the same? Can someone please give an elaborate explanation of it - What exactly are they signifying? Are they proportional to the Intake manifold pressure?

If I don't get the value of the pressures from the PID (say in Hyundai i10), is there any way to calculate them? Do their values remain the same more or less, or it changes with engine load?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs
PIDs: 0A and 22 (mode 1)

Comment: I'd assume they were the same. I've never observed anything other than the fuel rail pressure PID. AFAIK there is no way to determine fuel pressure without a electric or mechanical gauge/transducer. On Fords with FRP sensors they use a Fuel Pump Driver module which receives input from the ECM and adjusts fuel pressure accordingly.

Comment: How about a link to the webpage your talking about?  Help us be successful @soumyasen

Answer (score 10):

On a car with fuel injection there can be two fuel pumps, one high-pressure and one low-pressure.  The low-pressure pump moves the gas from the tank up to the high pressure pump.  The high pressure pump then raises the pressure to a level that will be useful to the injectors.  The two PIDs reflect those two different systems.

```
PID  Description        Min       Max      Units 
0A   Fuel pressure        0       765      kPa (gauge)
22   Fuel rail pressure   0     5,177.265  kPa  
23   Fuel rail pressure   0   655,350      kPa
```

You can also see that the range of values returned for each is scaled to be appropriate for the range of pressures to be measured.

(I took those PID values from Wikipedia so trust, but verify.)

**Edit:**  I added an entry for PID 23 as mentioned in comments and adjusted the layout of the max pressure column to highlight the difference in the scales of the data.  In OBDII there is no way to specify the units of measure for a given PID, that is part of the reason there are two PIDs for fuel rail pressure. PID 22 is appropriate to the pressures for injection into the intake manifold, while PID 23 is better matched against the pressures in diesel or direct gas injection.

To address the other points in the question.  Only PID 22 specifies that it is measured relative to manifold pressure, I would not expect that the other two would thake manifold pressure into account since they are not really affected by it.

These pressures are all controlled by regulators so that any of these PIDs should be fairly constant and not affected by load in a well running engine.  Low fuel pressure would be the result of failure or clog in the fuel system.

Comment: _In general, there are two fuel pumps on a car with fuel injection_ this would be a true statement for vehicle with direct injection, but most "fuel injection" cars only have one pump

Comment: @Movemorecommentslinktotop it also holds for some older ones as well.  My E30 BMW has two pumps, The low pressure one in the tank and then the high pressure one along the driver's rocker panel. But no OBDII on that one to prove out the whole thing.

Comment: Is it gas or diesel?

Comment: @Movemorecommentslinktotop it is gas.

Comment: @Movemorecommentslinktotop I also reworded the first sentence to better address your point.

Comment: Cool.. Can you please answer my remaining questions? I would be able to understand it better

Comment: I'm not convinced that PID 22 is the one for the high-pressure rail. PID 23 seems to be the right one for GDI and diesel setups